# European nomad, moving every few years. Tax residence and capital gains tax on purchase and sell of ETFs/Funds

Tags: capital-gains-tax, law, european-union, tax-residency

This might be a silly question.

Let's say I change jobs and country of residence-always within the European Union-every 3 years, purchasing monthly the same ETF through a local broker on each country (**A, B, C, and D**). This goes on for 12 years, after which I decide to take a sabbatical, move to a different European country (**E**), and start selling shares of the ETF to cover my expenses.

All five countries have different capital gains taxes. Which tax legislation applies? **Which capital gains tax rate is applicable to the shares I sell?**

In case that the applicable tax legislation is **that of the country from which the shares were purchased** (i.e. **A, B, C, or D**): if I had those shares in some sort of **tax wrapper accounts** (like UK's ISAs, or France's PEAs), would I still benefit from them?

Comment: If you are truly a "P.T."  Do you really want such an anchor, tying you to, uh, imperial issues?   Create an entity for yourself in an appropriate jurisdiction (Dubai, Singapore, who knows)  and send excess profits there.  (ie,Ddo exactly what, say, Apple does.  Why pay tax as you go along if you don't have to?)

Comment: I don't know what you mean or what a P.T. is. A "Part Timer"?

Comment: Perpetual Traveller

Comment: No, not really.